# Replace text for every first child for multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Two identical select boxes

```
<select class="select">
  <option>- OPTION -</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>

<select class="select">
  <option>- OPTION -</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

Replace `- OPTION -` with `- SELECT -`

```
$(".select option:first").text("- SELECT -");
```

Code above replaces only first select box, ignores the second. Why? How to apply to all/any?

https://jsfiddle.net/oLbfs901/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:first` will only select the first element of all the options combined together.

`:first-child` will select all elements that are the first child of their parent.

```
$(".select option:first-child").text("- SELECT -");
```

---

**UPDATE regarding speed**

Below, user @kosmos suggested using `.find()`. This method is much less performant than using `:first-child`. Some developers usually don't think twice about performance because it's still really quick but these can add up. Now you know that faster ways exist to achieve the same result so I would suggest using this knowledge.

This is the test case I set up to confirm: http://jsperf.com/find-versus-first-child

Answer (score 2):

Though the other answers are valid, you could also type

```
$(".select").find("option:first").text("- SELECT -");
```

to get all `.select` elements and, for each one, get the first `option` child.

Comment: Was thinking of this. Will be nice if you elaborate why find works here? Because if you use children then it won't work.

Comment: Although this is true, performance wise using :first-child is almost 3x faster than running a query like .find(). Check out this test I made and run the test: https://jsperf.com/find-versus-first-child

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I don't know if it's clearly stated in the docs, but when using `$elem.children(selector)`, jquery will first create a set of all children, then filter using the selector. So in your case the first option of the set will be returned. When using .find, it's different. jquery will first initalize with 2 subsets of `.select`, then loop over each of them to apply the find function using the selector

Comment: @Logar Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with below code

```
$(".select option:first-child").text("- SELECT -");
```